# Getting Error 'Cannot populate JSON' when insert data to Azure Mobile Service from c# Client

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am developing a Cordova-Ionic Application with Azure Mobile Service as back end.
I downloaded the .Net(C#) Backend Web Service from Azure Portal to work and then to publish to portal.
When I am trying to insert data to the SQL database table 'tblUser' I am getting below exception. No idea how it is happening. Please help me.

Error: "Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'client.tblUser'. Path '', line 1, position 1."
Below more points:

- Data getting successfully when execte select code
- Insert is success when try with local host. only happens when I publish it to portal
- I deleted current database and server in Portal, created new. But still error
- Dataobject structure are same in client and server
- before implementing in Cordova first I am testing to insert data using C# client(Windows Test application)

Below the code used in the client

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("http://mywebname.azurewebsites.net/");
IMobileServiceTable<tblUser> todoTable = client.GetTable<tblUser>(); 
await todoTable.InsertAsync(new tblUser() { 
    EmailId = "test@test.com", 
    Password = "pass1", 
    Name = "name 1", 
    IsActive = true
}); 
// Here I am getting exception(Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'client.tblUser'. Path '', line 1, position 1.)
```

Below more details;

I also tried with Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject instead of new tblUser(). Then it returns zero count array.

1. Below is the tblUser in client(Windows Application);

   public class tblUser
       {
           public string id { get; set; }
           public string EmailId { get; set; }
           public string Password { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public bool IsActive { get; set; }
           public string MobileNo { get; set; }
           public bool IsVerifiedEmail { get; set; }
           public bool IsVerifiedMobile { get; set; }
           public bool IsAllowedToContactMe { get; set; }
           public string VerificationTypeKey { get; set; }
          public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
           public int RoleCode { get; set; }
       }
2. TblUser in service

   public class tblUser : EntityData
       { 
           public string EmailId { get; set; }
           public string Password { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public bool IsActive { get; set; }
           public string MobileNo { get; set; }
           public bool IsVerifiedEmail { get; set; }
           public bool IsVerifiedMobile { get; set; }
           public bool IsAllowedToContactMe { get; set; }
           public string VerificationTypeKey { get; set; }
           public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
           public int RoleCode { get; set; }
       }
3. Modal includes below code;

   public DbSet tblUsers { get; set; }
           protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
           {
               modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                   new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention(
                       "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
           }
4. controler;

   protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
           {
               base.Initialize(controllerContext);
               aadhiappnameContext context = new aadhiappnameContext();
               DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager(context, Request);
           }

   ```
       // GET tables/tblUser
       public IQueryable<tblUser> GetAlltblUsers()
       {
           return Query();
       } 
       public SingleResult<tblUser> GettblUser(string id)
       {
           return Lookup(id);
       } 
       public Task<tblUser> PatchtblUser(string id, Delta<tblUser> patch)
       {
           return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
       }

       // POST tables/tblUser
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PosttblUser(tblUser item)
       {

           tblUser current = null;
           current = await InsertAsync(item); 
           return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current); 

       }


       public Task DeletetblUser(string id)
       {
           return DeleteAsync(id);
       }
   ```

Comment: what does your tblUser() look like?  What does your backend model and controller look like?  Have you got any diagnostics from the backend?

Comment: Try these steps for logging your outgoing requests: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#javascript--apache-cordova-client

Comment: You should be able to send a POST of a well-formed request to POST https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/tables/tblUser with the right headers (ZUMO-API-VERSION and an X-ZUMO-AUTH if you need to be authenticated) and a JSON payload that is the JSON serialization of your object.  It should show it inserted.  If it doesn't (error), then the error is in your backend.  If it does, the error is in your front end.  From there, you can refine your model and/or add additional debugging / step through debugger to find the real issue.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted project and database. created new one. now solved.